# What return value to use to match two different kinds of Types

Tags: sql, linq, object, methods, types

I'm using LINQ towards my MSSQL database. I have the TypeOfMetaData-table, the UserMetaData-table and the MetaDataHasType-table that has foreign-keys from the TypeOfMetaData- and the UserMetaData-table. What I need to do a method to get all MetaData and Types and return them. The problem is that I don't know what kind of return value I should use to be able to match the correct rows together.

Thanks for the help,

wardh

Comment: Can u give us example what do u need?

Comment: I need something to return that can contain several UserMetaData-objects and MetaDataHasType-objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an Anonymous Type (var) to store the result:

```
var result = 
  yourDataContext
  .UserMetaData_Table
  .Select(
    userMetaData => 
      new
      {
         UserMetaData = userMetaData,
         Types = userMetaData.MetaDataHasTypes.Select(types => types.TypeOfMetaData),
      })
  .ToArray();
```

If this isn't what you want, could you update you question to with an example of the data context and the classes you have and what you have tried so far.